# Adjusting Auto Layout view for keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, autolayout

I'm creating a login screen in my iPhone app using Auto Layout. Everything is working well and I'm using the basic template of this app: https://github.com/syoutsey/UIScrollViewAutolayout. Essentially, the view hierarchy is the following:

- View (superview)

  - Scroll View

    - Content View

      - Text Field 1
      - Text Field 2
      - Button

In order for the `UIScrollView` to be able to calculate it's `contentSize` I must unambiguously tie each control in the `Content View` together and then tie the bottom-most control (in this case the `button`) to the bottom of the `Content View`. This is all well and good but breaks the fundamental principle of Auto Layout in that things are not hard coded, only relationships are specified. How can I setup my UI elements so that they follow Auto Layout principles and the `Scroll View` is still able to dynamically calculate the `contentSize`?

Comment: You don't need a scroll view most likely. As long as all of your subviews are setup with the proper constraints you should be able to just change the bottom space constraint of one of you views and everything should move accordingly. Animating a couple of constraints will move everything for you exactly the same way.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/op183/ScrollViewAutoLayoutExampe

i added keyboard and login segue, to show you how to use autolayout. the basic idea is very simple

....
bottomToScrollView.constant = keyboardHeight
.....

just check the code, it is easy to folow